# Adding workflow in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I want to add workflow in my eclipse rcp. Please provide me some guidlines.
I tried few plugins, but they were not what I was looking for.

Comment: By workflow do you mean a modelling support? Do you want to create your own modeller?

Comment: Actually I am not getting a start point for this approach.So want to know any workthrough possible for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to essentially do is create an Eclipse modeling project. The way it works is by creating your own EMF models. All your tree nodes with their attributes are "modelled" in EMF.

Then you can convert this model to an GEF/Draw2d Diagram using something called GMF(Graphical Modeling Framework).

EMF :

http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/

GMF :

The GMF Tooling project provides a model-driven approach to generating graphical editors in Eclipse.

http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/?project=gmf-tooling

Tutorial : I would suggest looking at the following tutorial to get a feel of the whole thing.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-gmf/

Comment: Thank u so much Pushkar. You saved my day and time.